# Choosing top k models using GridSearchCV in scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Is there an easy/pre-existing way to perform a Grid Search in scikit-learn and then automatically return the top k best performing models or automatically average their outputs? I intend to try and reduce overfitting this way. I have not yet found anything related to this.

EDIT: To clarify, I know about sklearn's GridSearch, I am looking for an option to perform a Grid Search and then return the top k best performing models or average over them, rather than just returning the best single model.

Comment: [`Here`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) it is. Have a look and then be more specific.

Comment: @AruneshSingh As far as I can tell the default GridSearch does not have a utility for averaging over multiple hyperparameter choices, only giving the best one? Maybe I am missing something?

Comment: I believe no. But, then I think for that you may need to use ensemble models. Look at it [`Averaging methods`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have your fitted `GridSearchCV` object as `grid`, you can get the results for each parameter with `grid.cv_results_`. I usually load it as a pandas DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
results = pd.DataFrame(grid.cv_results_)
results.sort_values(by='rank_test_score', inplace=True)
```

Then you can get the parameters for each model from the `params` column. For example, I want the 2nd best parameter set:

```
params_2nd_best = results.loc[1, 'params']
clf_2nd_best = grid.best_estimator_.set_params(**params_2nd_best)
```

Comment: Not quite as elegant as I was hoping but can work with this, thank you!

Comment: What's not elegant about it? The cv_results_ are a dictionary, so you could do some traversing magic yourself. But the fact that it is meant to be cast into a Pandas dataframe (it is mentioned in the docs), without having the actual dependency in the sklearn project is for me quite nice and absolutely useful.